# Trying to connect to Sql Server using MAMP OS X

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, mamp

I need help please.
I am trying to make a connection to a Sql Server Database using Mamp on my Mac.

MS SQL Server Express 2012

I have followed this tutorial http://www.ziqijin.com/installing-the-mssql-module-for-mac-os-x/ and I am successfully displaying **mssql** and **pdo_dblib** in my phpinfo() page.

Heres a screen shot of my phpinfo() page.
http://southerncolour.com.au/screenshot.png

The PHP code I am using to connect is:

```html
try {
        $hostname = "scpbm01.xxx.com.au";
        $port = "1433";
        $dbname = "sclive";
        $username = "NAVUser";
        $pw = "xxxx";
     
        $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=",'$username','$pw');
     
      } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        exit;
      }
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message.

**Failed to get DB handle: SQLSTATE[01002] Adaptive Server connection failed (severity 9)**

Can anyone please help??

I have been trying for 2 days with no luck.

Cheers Dave